# Why does bacula restore fail?

Tags: backup, restore, bacula

I have bacula setup locally on my computer. I made a backup, then I deleted one of the files that was backed up. I opened up bconsole and ran the restore command to restore the file. The restore command didn't show any errors, and it said that it restored the file, but when I look in the directory, the file still isn't there.

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Yes, this happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `Where` option correctly during the restore? From [the manual:](http://www.bacula.org/5.1.x-manuals/en/main/main/Restore_Command.html)

> before running the job, please note that the default location for
>   restoring files is not their original locations, but rather the
>   directory `/tmp/bacula-restores`